# Worsening performance with mysql data insertion and entity framework

Tags: mysql, .net, linq-to-entities

I'm pulling match data from an online game API and saving details to a locally hosted mysql database.  Each call to the API returns about 100 matches and I'm inserting 15 matches at a time.  For each match i'm inserting anywhere from 150-250 rows in 5 tables.

I've used the optimizations described here: [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)

I've been able to insert about 9 matches/sec but now that I've saved 204,000 matches the insertion time has slowed to 2.5 matches/sec.  I hope to save all matches since inception which is probably around 300+ million matches.

I can't use SqlBulkCopy because this is a mysql database.

Is there any further optimizations that I can do?  I'd like to parallelize, but I suppose I'll still be blocked on DB.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)? There's no way you can insert hundreds of millions of records using a framework no matter how awesome the framework is. Even at 9 matches/sec insertion speed that'll take over a year to add.

Comment: No I haven't but this is probably a much better choice which I didn't think about.  I guess I can just save all the calls to csv, and then use that to insert everything.  It'll also make it easier to parallelize.

Comment: It's really hard to beat the raw performance of `LOAD DATA INFILE`, it's often faster than the equivalent SQL. Also when inserting, if you can, disable indexes and turn them back on at the end of your mass insert.